# atom-editor cmd-click for multi-cursors not working anymore after cmd-click on a hyperlink

Tags: atom-editor

atom editor on mac osx related:

I did cmd-click on a hyperlink and got a popup (lost it before able to read),
and now my cmd-click to set multiple cursors is not working any more.

anybody can tell me how to reactivate multi-cursor by cmd-click again?

Comment: If you have setup the same event for different actions, how would Atom know which action it should launch on that event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found it finally ... it was hyperclick plugin which redefined cmd-click.

But I had hyperclick plugin installed for months, it never interrupted multi-cursor from working ...

anyway ... kind of rubber duck debugging ...

Comment: I have a same problem, command+click for multiline cursor just stop working, but I do not know how to fix it, I do not have hyperlink installed

Comment: This is probably a new bug that was just introduced with the new version v1.48.0 (2020-06-10). I also started experiencing this just now

Comment: should be fixed in the next version by https://github.com/atom/atom/pull/20804

Comment: @taga @A Campos Here is a temporary fix: in the Settings pane, click on the "Open Config Folder" button and find config.cson. Add the first few lines that appear in this comment. https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/20916#issuecomment-642361826. Save the file and breathe a sigh of relief.

Comment: for me it was `atom-ide-ui`

Answer (score 16):

For a temporary fix:

1. open the console (you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> shortcut, respectively <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> shortcut on MacOS),
2. run `atom.config.set('core.editor.multiCursorOnClick', true);`.

**Notes:**
You might also want to take a look at your `hyperclick` or `atom-ide-hyperclick` package. In atom preferences, go to `Settings` and change the `Trigger keys for MacOS` to become `command + click`.

Answer (score 5):

I've solved this issue by changing the trigger keys to shift+control+click, in `atom-ide-ui`, under the `Hyperclick` section.

Comment: I've changed it in IDE settings and then back. Now `cmd+click` goes to definition (atom-ide default) and `cmd+shift+click` adds multiple cursors

Answer (score 2):

The hyperclick module is now part of the IDE module and having both hyperclick and IDE installed causes this problem, too. Deleting the old hyperclick module fixes it (the IDE module by itself does not seem to cause the problem).

Answer (score 1):

Because of the hyperlink installed, Multi Cursor key is now `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `Mouse Click` in windows. For me it's working.
You can try on Mac `CMD` + `SHIFT` + `Mouse Click`

Answer (score 0):

If someone is facing the same issue on Linux, these methods helped me

#### Method 1

1. Navigate to `/home/<Your Username>/.atom/`
2. Find the `config.cson` file
3. Add the following lines to the file

```
 "*":
  core:
    editor:
      multiCursorOnClick: true
```

4. Save the file and start Atom

If this method does **NOT** work, follow this

#### Method 2

1. Uninstall Atom
2. Navigate to `/home/<Your Username>/`
3. Remove/Delete `.atom` directory
4. Reinstall Atom
5. Redo **Method 1**

It should work.
Hope it helps!